# Error Parsing attribute 'page'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Keep Getting this error when running Site:

> Error parsing attribute 'page': Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' from its string representation '' for the 'Page' property.

.aspx file:

```
<%@  Page Title="Home Page" Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class ="Home1">

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

vb file:

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

End Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take out the word page, and just keep Language (you already used it at the start)

```
Language="VB"
```